# the difference between = and <- operator in the function system.time()

Tags: r, assignment-operator

I am using the function system.time() and I have discovered something which surprises me. I often use the allocation symbol “=” instead of “<-”. I am aware most R users use “<-” but I consider “=” clearer in my codes. Thus, I used “=” to allocate a value in a function system.line() and the following error message appeared : Error: unexpected '=' in "system.time(a[,1] ="

Here is the code :

```
a = matrix(1, nrow = 10000)

require(stats)
system.time(a[,1] = a[,1]*2) #this line doesn't work 
#Error: unexpected '=' in "system.time(a[,1] ="
system.time(a[,1] = a[,1]*2) #this line works
system.time(for(i in 1:100){a[,1] = a[,1]*i}) #this line works!!!!
```

I found : [Is there a technical difference between "=" and "<-"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140694/is-there-a-technical-difference-between-and) which explains that I can’t use “=” in a function to allocate since it is the symbol to assign argument in a function. But I have been surprised to see that it can work sometimes (see following code).

Does anyone know why it works here? (also why it doesn't work in the first case since I guess, a[,1] is not a parameter of the function system.time()...)

Thank you very much. 
Edwin.

Comment: this has been asked before. Your code is valid because you it is wrapped in `{ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `system.time(a[,1] = a[,1]*2)` the equals sign does not mean assignment, it is interpreted as an attempt to bind a "named argument"; but `system.time` does not have an argument of that name.

In `system.time(for(i in 1:100){a[,1] = a[,1]*i})` the equals sign really is doing an assignment; and that works fine.

If you wrote `system.time(a[,1] <- a[,1]*2)` the `<-` can only mean assignment, not argument binding, and it works!

But beware! If you wrote `system.time(a[,1] < - a[,1]*2)`, it also "works" but probably doesn't do what you meant!

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your code in `{ ... }` braces and it will work:

```
system.time({a[,1] = a[,1]*2})
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0
```

---

From `?"<-"`

> The operators <- and = assign into the environment in which they are
>   evaluated. The operator <- can be used anywhere, whereas the operator
>   = is only allowed at the top level (e.g., in the complete expression typed at the command prompt) or as one of the subexpressions in a
>   braced list of expressions.

Comment: It sounds even more weird for me. I'll use this method now, thanks. Why is that? Does anyone has any idea of the reason why "{ ... }" makes the code working? Thanks

Comment: it's because you are telling the parser that you want it to assign values to an object, rather than creating a list to pass to a function.

Comment: Or better yet start using `<-` for assignment!