# Calculate the Mortality Rates of COVID-19 in R

Tags: r

How to calculate the mortality rates of COVID-19 in R? Would you please give me more information about how to get it? Thank you in advance!

R codes:

```
newcasesofcovid19=c(1 ,   2  ,  0  ,  2  ,  1  ,  8  ,  1 ,   0  ,  1  ,  1  ,  1  ,  0 ,   0   , 1  
,  0, 1 ,   3  ,  3  ,  1  ,  0  ,  2  ,  8  ,  2  ,  3  ,  2  ,  2  ,  4 ,   4  ,  2  ,  2,
5  ,  2  ,  2   , 2  ,  6  ,  8  ,  5  ,  3  ,  1  ,  3  , 11  ,  8  ,  1  ,  4  ,  4,
7  ,  5  ,  3  , 13  , 12  ,  0  , 43  , 16  , 16  , 15  , 15  , 36  , 35  , 38  , 62,
83 ,  76 , 152 , 152  ,141  ,191  ,260  ,288 , 242 , 207 , 309 , 235 , 344 , 344 ,278,
299 , 297 , 348 , 331 , 267 , 367 , 302 , 389 , 278 , 278 , 278 , 262 , 392 , 351 , 329,
353 , 373 , 361 , 565 , 565 , 565 , 575 ,2169 ,1685 , 475 , 339 , 536 , 529 , 540 , 540,
540 , 443 , 399 , 681  ,738 , 814 , 576 , 610 , 749 , 749 , 749 , 749 , 623 , 560  ,658,
345 , 354 , 650 , 590 , 590 , 590,  590 , 413 , 394 , 722 , 615 , 621 , 497 , 375 , 375,
375 , 375 , 549 , 506 , 459 , 403 , 325 , 231 , 432 , 296 , 296 , 296 , 296 , 296 , 234,
415 , 413 , 396 , 402 , 652 , 652 , 652 , 652 , 652 , 655 , 651 , 676 , 585  ,552 , 968,
968 , 968 , 968 , 968 , 765  ,758 ,1177, 1264 ,1213 ,1435 ,1435, 1435 ,1435 ,1435,1435,
1374 ,1292, 1272 , 744 , 251 , 251,  251 , 251,  251 , 251)

deaths= c( 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0  ,0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 
0  ,0 , 0 , 0,0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 
0 , 0 , 1,0 ,2  ,2 , 2 , 1 , 3 ,1 , 0,  2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 5 , 6,  6 ,15 ,16, 15,  8 ,25, 12, 25, 
25,  18, 24, 35, 23, 38, 30, 38 ,30 ,34 ,28 ,28, 28, 46, 45, 51 ,32, 51, 54, 44, 61,61 ,61, 70, 75, 
46, 40,51 ,55,55 ,41, 41 ,41 ,34, 34, 69 ,71 ,49, 34, 41, 43, 43, 43, 43 ,43, 36, 35, 15, 22, 37, 40, 
40,40, 40 ,24 ,18, 35 ,32, 29, 27, 22,22, 22, 22, 19, 28, 19, 12, 18, 11, 17, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,  6,
10 ,15 , 9 ,14 ,15, 15,15, 15, 15 , 4,  9, 13 , 9, 11,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  9,  7 , 9,  6,  8,  5,
 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 0 , 0, 1,  0,  0,  0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0)
data=cbind(newcasesofcovid19,deaths)
data
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a vector it's `mortality_rate <- deaths/newcasesofcovid19`

If you want your data to be in a dataframe then use `data.frame()` instead of `cbind()`. With `cbind()` you're creating a matrix. Then it is simply:

```
df <- data.frame(newcasesofcovid19, deaths, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$mortality_rate <- df$deaths/df$newcasesofcovid19
```

Output

```
  newcasesofcovid19 deaths mortality_rate
1                15      3      0.2000000
2               262     46      0.1755725
3               339     51      0.1504425
4               351     51      0.1452991
5               373     54      0.1447721
6               353     51      0.1444759
...
```

Also, you should be assigning variables with the `<-` operator rather than `=`... here's a good post on why: [Is there a technical difference between "=" and "<-"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140694/is-there-a-technical-difference-between-and)

Answer (score -1):

```
c(1 ,   2  ,  0  ,  2  ,  1  ,  8  ,  1 ,   0  ,  1  ,  1  ,  1  ,  0 ,   0   , 1  
,  0, 1 ,   3  ,  3  ,  1  ,  0  ,  2  ,  8  ,  2  ,  3  ,  2  ,  2  ,  4 ,   4  ,  2  ,  2,
5  ,  2  ,  2   , 2  ,  6  ,  8  ,  5  ,  3  ,  1  ,  3  , 11  ,  8  ,  1  ,  4  ,  4,
7  ,  5  ,  3  , 13  , 12  ,  0  , 43  , 16  , 16  , 15  , 15  , 36  , 35  , 38  , 62,
83 ,  76 , 152 , 152  ,141  ,191  ,260  ,288 , 242 , 207 , 309 , 235 , 344 , 344 ,278,
299 , 297 , 348 , 331 , 267 , 367 , 302 , 389 , 278 , 278 , 278 , 262 , 392 , 351 , 329,
353 , 373 , 361 , 565 , 565 , 565 , 575 ,2169 ,1685 , 475 , 339 , 536 , 529 , 540 , 540,
540 , 443 , 399 , 681  ,738 , 814 , 576 , 610 , 749 , 749 , 749 , 749 , 623 , 560  ,658,
345 , 354 , 650 , 590 , 590 , 590,  590 , 413 , 394 , 722 , 615 , 621 , 497 , 375 , 375,
375 , 375 , 549 , 506 , 459 , 403 , 325 , 231 , 432 , 296 , 296 , 296 , 296 , 296 , 234,
415 , 413 , 396 , 402 , 652 , 652 , 652 , 652 , 652 , 655 , 651 , 676 , 585  ,552 , 968,
968 , 968 , 968 , 968 , 765  ,758 ,1177, 1264 ,1213 ,1435 ,1435, 1435 ,1435 ,1435,1435,
1374 ,1292, 1272 , 744 , 251 , 251,  251 , 251,  251 , 251)

deaths= c( 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0  ,0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 
0  ,0 , 0 , 0,0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 
0 , 0 , 1,0 ,2  ,2 , 2 , 1 , 3 ,1 , 0,  2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 5 , 6,  6 ,15 ,16, 15,  8 ,25, 12, 25, 
25,  18, 24, 35, 23, 38, 30, 38 ,30 ,34 ,28 ,28, 28, 46, 45, 51 ,32, 51, 54, 44, 61,61 ,61, 70, 75, 
46, 40,51 ,55,55 ,41, 41 ,41 ,34, 34, 69 ,71 ,49, 34, 41, 43, 43, 43, 43 ,43, 36, 35, 15, 22, 37, 40, 
40,40, 40 ,24 ,18, 35 ,32, 29, 27, 22,22, 22, 22, 19, 28, 19, 12, 18, 11, 17, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,  6,
10 ,15 , 9 ,14 ,15, 15,15, 15, 15 , 4,  9, 13 , 9, 11,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  9,  7 , 9,  6,  8,  5,
 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 0 , 0, 1,  0,  0,  0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0)
data=cbind(newcasesofcovid19,deaths)
```

Comment: This does not really give an answer to OP's question on how to calculate the mortality rate. Please add an explanation and maybe additional steps in the code.