# How do you normalize data using R package bestnormalize?

Tags: r

I am unable plot a histogram of normalized data from the `penguins` data set.

```r
library(bestnormalize)
data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins")
ppp <- penguins

bestNormalize(ppp$flipper_length_mm)
ok <- orderNorm(ppp$flipper_length_mm)
newflip <- boxcox(flipper_length_mm)
hist(newflip)
## Error in hist.default(newflip) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Answer (score 0):

The function gives a list object. The normalized data are in the list with the name `x.t` and can be extracted with the `$` operator. Likewise the the Box-Cox transformed values are `x.t` values stored in the `newflip` list and must be passed to `histogram` function using `$` operator- Here the code is rewritten according to the question, and to get the best answer, my advise is to read the vignette `?bestNormalize` and check if other parameters should be taken into consideration when performing normalization using the package:

```
library(bestNormalize)

set.seed(111)
ppp<-penguins

data_norm<-bestNormalize(ppp$bill_length_mm
                         ,allow_orderNorm = T
                         )

data_norm<-data_norm$x.t
hist(data_norm)

newflip=boxcox(ppp$flipper_length_mm)

hist(newflip$x.t)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing an error because you're passing the `newflip` to the function (which is a list). As per the `boxcox` function's help (use `?boxcos` to access function's documentation), the output of the function is a list comprising of the following:

> A **list** of class boxcox with elements:
>
> `x.t` transformed original data
>
> `x`   original data
>
> ... (other elements in the list)

So if you pass `newflip$x.t` to the `hist` function it should work.

Below is a more complete (reproducible) answer:

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(bestNormalize)

data(penguins)
ppp <- penguins

bestNormalize(ppp$flipper_length_mm)
ok <- orderNorm(ppp$flipper_length_mm)
# There's a base function with the same name; so best 
# use :: specify the package
newflip <- bestNormalize::boxcox(ppp$flipper_length_mm)
newflip

hist(newflip$x.t)
```

**BONUS MATERIAL**

1. In R use `<-` as the assignment operator. There's a subtle difference between `<-` and `=`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6140807/2153244) for details.
2. While `hist()` function is ok for a quick glance, use `ggplot2` for better graphs. See [this document](https://rpubs.com/arvindpdmn/ggplot2-basics) for details.